# Getting Error after Install MySql

Tags: mysql

I installed MySql Server & MySql Client. But I am getting error while running `mysql -V` command.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You haven't provided you OS/release, and whilst your messages imply *jammy* or 22.04, they details provided in your paste is incorrect for *jammy* or 22.04, is your machine updated?  `mysql-client-core-8.0 | 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`

Comment: Why don't you uninstall what you installed, then use the command suggested by your screenshot?

Comment: Thanks @DanielT. I tried in that way but I am getting same result.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc. I tired in this way.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOe3F.png

Comment: Please `echo $PATH` and `ls /usr/bin/mysql` and `apt-cache policy mysql-client-core-8.0` and try `/usr/bin/mysql -V`

Comment: Please also copy and paste from your terminal, and into a [code block] not a screenshot next time

Comment: Thanks @DanielT. I am getting this output `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` after running command `echo $PATH`.

Comment: @DanielT. I am getting this output `ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/mysql': No such file or directory` after running command `ls /usr/bin/mysql`.

Comment: @DanielT. I am getting this ouput `bash: /usr/bin/mysql: No such file or directory` after running command `/usr/bin/mysql -V`

Comment: Did you add any bad third-party sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` or `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Remove them, run `apt update`, and reinstall mysql